# How to hide Url values in Play Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

How to hide the values in the URL? In routes:

```
GET    /admin/:userId       com.example.sample.getUser(userId: Int)
```

When `getUser` action is requested, URL returns in the format as shown below:

```
http://localhost:9000/admin/0
```

I don't want to view the `userId` in the URL.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @marcospereira: User guess other user id to do any malfunction, of course i check current user login from session but its not fair to view id in url.

Comment: You are trying to have security through obscurity which is not the best way to... have security. If you hide the user ID using a POST request, any user can still guess and request other users information. You can use a non incremental and predictable id generator (like uuid), but you still have to provide other security guarantees at your backend code.

Answer (score 0):

This is common `GET` vs `POST` difference. In `GET` request params are sent within the URL, in POST are not.

If you need to avoid params in the URL just use a HTML `form` with hidden field instead of  `a` tag to send the requests and in your controller fetch the `POST` arguments, dummy HTML sample:

```
<form action="/admin/" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="@userId" >
   <input type="submit" value="@userName" > 
</form>
```

It will give you submit button with name of the user as a label, you can use CSS to give it feel and look of common link.

Note that's invalid REST pattern, as POST shouldn't be used to showing data, you don't mention what is the purpose of this, so maybe you should rethink your needs.

Maybe you can also just make usage of parameters with *default* or *fixed* values:
[**check the docs for more options**](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaRouting#Parameters-with-fixed-values)

Comment: Thanks for your post , i tried your post, i already have form tag,  i put inside another form like your post, form submissions not working correctly.

Comment: My sample is just for showing that possibility, you must fit it to your needs and handle this request in the controller properly